# iOS - UI is not transforming with device rotation change

Tags: ios, iphone, orientation, mpmovieplayercontroller, uiinterfaceorientation

I am working on orientation and Movie Player. The functionality is as follows:

- If I turn on full screen mode of MPMoviePlayer then it should open in landscape mode only.
- If I rotate my device to landscape, then it will automatically starts full screen mode of MPMoviePlayer
- And again it should come back to portrait mode when I turn off
  fullscreen mode of MPMoviePlayer or rotate device to portrait mode.

Now Problem is that, it goes to full screen mode on device rotation to landscape mode

**but at the time of come back, The UI is not transforming to portrait mode properly.**

**This Problem is only with iOS 8.1, 8.2. It is working fine in iOS 7.* and 8.3, 8.4.**

Please look at attached screens:

**Before Full screen:**

[image]

**After full screen:**

[image]

**Come back to portrait mode:**

[image]

I have used this code to handle orientation:

`allowRotation` is Boolean property declared in `AppDelegate.h` file

//Adding observer for movie player orientation event In App Delegate

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:) name:MPMoviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification object:nil];
```

// Observer methods

```
- (void) moviePlayerWillEnterFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {

    allowRotation = YES;
}


- (void) moviePlayerWillExitFullscreenNotification:(NSNotification*)notification {

    allowRotation = NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)window{

    if (([[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isKindOfClass:[MPMoviePlayerViewController class]]  && ![[self.window.rootViewController presentedViewController] isBeingDismissed]) || allowRotation)
    {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeLeft | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscapeRight;
    }
    else{

        allowRotation= NO;
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    }
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}
```

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

## Do

In your `UIViewController`, implement

```
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // Do the dynamic logic here
}
```

## Don't

Do not ignore the `window` parameter passed in:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application
      supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window
```

*Your current code is actually not responding to the question: ForWindow.*

---

The general practice is to return

1. **all the possible orientations** for a given window (you typically only have a single window per application) in `supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow`
2. a subset of that list, which can be dynamic, in the view controller `supportedInterfaceOrientations`.

## Example

```
// App delegate
- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)application:(UIApplication *)application supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(nullable UIWindow *)window {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

// View controller
-(UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```